# Flutter Shared Preferences Android alarm manager plus not getting the latest value

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

When app is paused I setup an alarm that runs every one minute and when app is resumed I cancel the timer. But when I get the data when app is resumed I don't get the latest data. I get data of the previous value when app was paused. But if the app is detached then I get the latest value.
How do I solve this problem. Thank You.

```dart
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print('app $state');
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        update(1, updateTime);
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        final sec = await Utils.getInt('saveTimeEveryMin');
        print('app Resumed: $sec');
        cancel(1); // alarm cancel
        break;
      default:
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
  
  update(int id, Function callback) async {
    print('alram: started ${DateTime.now()}');
    final value = await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      Duration(minutes: 1),
      id,
      callback,
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
    print('is alarm on? $value');
  }
  
  void updateTime() async {
    print('update ${DateTime.now()}');
    int? time = await Utils.getInt('saveTimeEveryMin');

    (time == null) ? time = 60 : time -= 60;
    await Utils.saveInt('saveTimeEveryMin', time);
    print('updated $time ${DateTime.now()}');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today and I found out some solutions from flutter workmanager(the same issue was happening there as well). You can check that issue by clicking [here](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/220).

In Short, you can use the `reload()` function provided in SharedPreferences Package which fetches updated values

or

add a one-second delay for before getting an instance of `SharedPreferences` in the callback function of AlarmManager

In My Case, I had to Do both to fix this issue,

Comment: Thanks. Doing both worked for me.